# Black Screen between Scriptsetup and Login (Ubuntu 16.04.1)

Tags: boot, drivers, nvidia, screen, gpu

**My ultimate question is at the bottom!**

Hello, I am BRAND NEW TO LINUX. I just installed Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS *Xenial Xerus* on a computer I put together myself some years ago. *No other OS on the disk.* It's entirely AMD: Processor is Phenom II x4 965, motherboard is a gigabyte 64-bit system, and a 90 GB SSD. The OS is reporting my Graphics card as Gallium 0.4 on NVCE in Details (what?), but as Geforce GTX 560 (fermi) from Zotac in Software & Updates. The latter is correct.

**Here's the problem**: if I restart or turn off the system, I get all the way to the scriptsetup screen where I enter my passphrase...only to be greeted by a black screen (rather than the login page on my desktop).

**Fix Attempts:** I tried multiple fixes I found littered through this site to no avail. *Recovery mode* fixed nothing. *Nomodeset* works on second boot up attempt (first one = no keyboard) Once I get through to that mode, I seem to have *read-only access*, so nothing I do in that mode fixes anything. I couldn't do anything to the grub files at least.

I *reinstalled* Ubuntu 16.04 so I could get back to the desktop, but I'm afraid to turn it off or restart for fear of the same issue. Is the NVIDIA binary driver version 361.42 the correct driver? Currently, it is set to X.org X server (Nouveau). _What do I do?

**How do I ensure my hardware (esp GPU) is working with Linux properly so I don't get the black screen after unlocking the scryptsetup?**

Answer (score 0):

So I changed the driver to nvidia version 361.42, and added directions in nvidia settings to the registry key files via the terminal...I found directions in another question entry. Just turned my computer off and back on, and it appears to be working fine! Hopefully, this fixed the problem permanently. I'd really like to get back to worrying about coding instead so.

Comment: Hello A.Bergeron, would you mind to provide more detail? Like what kind of nvidia settings did you do? Thank you !

Comment: I opened a terminal and installed nvidia-settings via sudo. Then I used bash script to add paths to the two latest drivers on my system. 

I hope I'm making sense here, I've been a Linux user for 2 days now. So I literally have no idea what I'm doing.

Comment: I dont know if I did anything to nvidia settings, I just changed drivers in the software center, and then typed in the PATHS in the terminal according to an answered question somewhere in the site.This is the code I added: "ln -s /etc/alternatives/x86_64-linux-gnu_nvidia_app_profile_keys nvidia-application-profiles-340.96-key-documentation",  "ln -s /etc/alternatives/x86_64-linux-gnu_nvidia_app_profile nvidia-application-profiles-340.96-rc". I did that for the 361.96 driver as well. This was after typing in the two following lines: "mkdir -p /etc/nvidia", "cd /etc/nvidia" after entering bash